# Eclipse on mac delete reversed without fn

Tags: eclipse, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-yosemite

Shortcuts in Eclipse Luna on mac are going crazy. On Yosemite 10.10.5 the delete button was not deleting files by default. So after rebinding the delete key to deleting files the delete key works as if the function (fn) key was pressed and deletes text from forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a while of frustration I found the issue. Rebinding the delete key removed the "**delete next**" field. Adding a delete to it fixed the issue.